# Simplifying a function in R

Tags: r

I have functions like;

```
funtosimplify <- function(x){
    return(0.4 * (x[1] * 1 + x[2] * 1.4 - 3.5)^2 + 0.3 * (x[1] * 
        1 + x[2] * 1.4 - 3)^2 + 0.2 * (x[1] * 1 + x[2] * 1.3 - 
        3.2)^2 + 0.1 * (x[1] * 1 + x[2] * 1.5 - 3.1)^2)
}
```

which should be;

```
funsimplified <- function(x){
    1 * x[1]^2 + 2.78 * x[1] * x[2] - 6.5 * x[1] + 1.935 * x[2]^2 - 9.034 * x[2] + 10.609
}
```

I've checked the similar issues and tried mostly recommended package `Ryacas` but it doesn't work for huge functions, so here it's useless for me. How can we make it possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to change it? Both functions will return the same values, right? What's the issue?

Comment: I'm using a package to solve nonlinear optimization problems, it works way faster when the objective function is in the simplest form. that is the reason.

Comment: You say that `yacas` will have difficulty with "huge" functions, but you offer a rather simple task as an example and put no bounds on the level of complexity, i.e. nothing about number of terms, degrees of polynomials, nesting of terms, exponentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Ryacas0** To use Ryacas0 create the original function which should be a single statement and with no brace brackets around the body nor return keyword.  Convert the body to character, replace x[i] with xi for all i, convert it to yacas using Sym, Simplify it, create a template for the result and convert the simplified expression to character, parse it and inject it into the body of the template.  In the example below f is the input and fs is the simplified output.

```
library(Ryacas0)

f <- function(x)
    0.4 * (x[1] * 1 + x[2] * 1.4 - 3.5)^2 + 0.3 * (x[1] * 
        1 + x[2] * 1.4 - 3)^2 + 0.2 * (x[1] * 1 + x[2] * 1.3 - 
        3.2)^2 + 0.1 * (x[1] * 1 + x[2] * 1.5 - 3.1)^2

txt <- deparse1(body(f))
txt2 <- gsub("x\\[(\\d)\\]", "x\\1", txt)
s <- Sym(txt2)
s2 <- Simplify(s)

fs <- function(x, x1 = x[1], x2 = x[2]) {}
body(fs) <- parse(text = as.character(s2))

fs
## function (x, x1 = x[1], x2 = x[2]) 
## 1 * x1^2 + (2.78 * (x1 * x2) - 6.5 * x1) + (1.935 * x2^2 - 9.034 * 
##     x2 + 10.609)

f(1:2)
## [1] 0.341

fs(1:2)
## [1] 0.341
```

**2) Ryacas** With Ryacas (as opposed to Ryacas0) it is the same except replace the lines that set s and s2 with

```
s <- ysym(txt2)
s2 <- simplify(s)
```

**3) mpoly** Since f above is a multivariable polynomial we can use mpoly.  txt2 is from (1) above.

```
library(mpoly)

p <- mp(txt2, stars = TRUE)
fs2 <- as.function(p, varorder = sort(vars(p)))
fs2
## function(.) {.[1]**2+2.78*.[1]*.[2]-6.5*.[1]+1.935*.[2]**2-9.034*.[2]+10.609}

fs2(1:2)
## [1] 0.341
```

Comment: Thank you! but here I get the same error with what `Ryacas` says, it doesn't work for huge functions either. the error is; Yacas returned this error: CommandLine(1) : Max evaluation stack depth reached.
Please use MaxEvalDepth to increase the stack size as needed.

Comment: (a) As the error message says, set the MaxEvalDepth. `yacas("MaxEvalDepth(10000)")` or some other number or (b) possibly there is an infinite recursion in your function in which case that needs to be fixed or (c) since f is a second degree polynomial and that equals its Taylor series to the second order terms calculate the Taylor series of it by replacing the `s2<- ...` line above with `s2 <- Simplify(Taylor(Taylor(s, "x1", 0, 2), "x2", 0, 2))`   or (d) break up the function and Simplify each part separately. (e) given that f is a multivariable polynomial have added (3) to the answer.